# SQL DeadLock involving two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

Here I got the deadlock from our production server.

```
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,waiter id=process95ca94988 mode=RangeS-U requestType=wait
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,waiter-list
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,owner id=process4761948 mode=X
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,owner-list
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,keylock hobtid=72057594753449984 dbid=5 objectname=LiveDB.dbo.Grsc indexname=PK_Grsc id=lock545d65e80 mode=X associatedObjectId=72057594753449984
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,waiter id=process4761948 mode=Sch-S requestType=wait
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,waiter-list
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,owner id=process95ca94988 mode=Sch-M
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,owner-list
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,objectlock lockPartition=7 objid=2127359389 subresource=FULL dbid=5 objectname=LiveDB.dbo.Assets id=lock4d7548900 mode=Sch-M associatedObjectId=2127359389
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,resource-list
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1648073703]
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,inputbuf
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,EXEC usp_Grsc_1 @POID<c/>@PODetailIDString<c/>@UserID<c/>@ProcessID
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,frame procname=LiveDB.dbo.usp_CScGr line=59 stmtstart=6770 stmtend=7156 sqlhandle=0x03000500e79b3b62b09a2d0125a300000100000000000000
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,UPDATE Grsc SET ForexID = @ForexGRNID WHERE PODtlInv IN (12632,12311,23134)
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,frame procname=LiveDB.dbo.usp_Grsc_1 line=493 stmtstart=69646 stmtend=70004 sqlhandle=0x0300050068a4f1565a9e2d0125a300000100000000000000
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,executionStack
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,process id=process95ca94988 taskpriority=0 logused=22088 waitresource=KEY: 5:72057594753449984 (4bbc256675eb) waittime=882 ownerId=15915819604 transactionname=CreateScgrPOdtl lasttranstarted=2014-05-15T10:25:21.887 XDES=0x10f760ce80 lockMode=RangeS-U schedulerid=37 kpid=10788 status=suspended spid=257 sbid=2 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=2 lastbatchstarted=2014-05-15T10:25:21.883 lastbatchcompleted=2014-05-15T10:25:21.883 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=P2 hostpid=6672 loginname=xxx isolationlevel=serializable (4) xactid=15915819604 currentdb=5 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=673185824 clientoption2=128056
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1648073703]
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,inputbuf
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,EXEC usp_Grsc_1 @POID<c/>@PODetailIDString<c/>@UserID<c/>@ProcessID
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,frame procname=LiveDB.dbo.usp_CScGr line=59 stmtstart=6770 stmtend=7156 sqlhandle=0x03000500e79b3b62b09a2d0125a300000100000000000000
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,executionStack
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,process id=process4761948 taskpriority=0 logused=1132 waitresource=OBJECT: 5:2127359389:7  waittime=2806 ownerId=15915837882 transactionname=CreateScgrPOdtl lasttranstarted=2014-05-15T10:25:25.080 XDES=0x11add9ef30 lockMode=Sch-S schedulerid=8 kpid=17484 status=suspended spid=216 sbid=2 ecid=0 priority=0 trancount=1 lastbatchstarted=2014-05-15T10:25:25.080 lastbatchcompleted=2014-05-15T10:25:25.080 clientapp=.Net SqlClient Data Provider hostname=P2 hostpid=6672 loginname=xxx isolationlevel=read committed (2) xactid=15915837882 currentdb=5 lockTimeout=4294967295 clientoption1=673185824 clientoption2=128056
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,process-list
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,deadlock victim=process4761948
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid29s,Unknown,deadlock-list
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x00000011ADD9EF30 Mode: Sch-S SPID:216 BatchID:2 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000011AEA4A538) Value:0xc42d9a80 Cost:(0/1132)
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Victim Resource Owner:
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Log Viewer could not read information for this log entry. Cause: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.. Content:
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x00000010F760CE80 Mode: RangeS-U SPID:257 BatchID:2 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000010F5236538) Value:0xd21ab800 Cost:(0/22088)
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Requested by:
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Input Buf: RPC Event: Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1648073703]
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,SPID: 216 ECID: 0 Statement Type: ALTER TABLE Line #: 262
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Owner:0x0000000696120E40 Mode: X        Flg:0x40 Ref:0 Life:02000000 SPID:216 ECID:0 XactLockInfo: 0x00000011ADD9EF70
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Grant List 0:
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,KEY: 5:72057594753449984 (4bbc256675eb) CleanCnt:2 Mode:X Flags: 0x1
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Node:2
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Log Viewer could not read information for this log entry. Cause: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.. Content:
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x00000011ADD9EF30 Mode: Sch-S SPID:216 BatchID:2 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000011AEA4A538) Value:0xc42d9a80 Cost:(0/1132)
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Requested by:
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Input Buf: RPC Event: Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1648073703]
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,SPID: 257 ECID: 0 Statement Type: UPDATE Line #: 493
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Owner:0x0000000622725340 Mode: Sch-M    Flg:0x40 Ref:0 Life:20000000 SPID:257 ECID:0 XactLockInfo: 0x00000010F760CEC0
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Grant List 2:
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,OBJECT: 5:2127359389:7         CleanCnt:2 Mode:Sch-M Flags: 0x1
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Node:1
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Log Viewer could not read information for this log entry. Cause: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.. Content:
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Wait-for graph
        05/15/2014 10:25:28,spid12s,Unknown,Deadlock encountered .... Printing deadlock information
```

Can anyone please explain me the scene here as these are two different tables involved...
Table Grsc is involved while updating the column value and  Assets table involved because of statement
        ALTER TABLE Assets ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
Even inside the Trigger procedure there is no reference to Grsc table. 
Both these update and alter statement are in same Stored Proc.

Now my question is, Is it possible that because of lock partition, deadlock situation arise? 
Since two different tables are involved, why in the first place deadlock should arise.?
Scratching my head, Can anyone help?

Thanks and Regards,

Amit Jog

Comment: Can you post the codes(procedure,trigger) please?

Comment: Hi Arnab, Sorry but I can not post the entire code, at the most I can post the actual line which was mentioned in the  deadlock graph.

Comment: This log is only from connection `spid29s`. There must be another connection payload that leads to deadlock. It could be these tables you are looking at are not involved in the deadlock at all.

Comment: I am updating the DeadLock grpah with the full deadlock log recvd for this particular deadlock

Comment: Do you have a foreign key relationship exists between these tables ?